# Replace repetitive number with NAN values except the first, in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2
  1       A
  2       A
  3       B
  4       C
  5       C
  6       C
  7       B
  8       B
  9       A
```

Now we can see that there is continuous occurrence of A, B and C. I want only the rows where the occurrence is starting. And the other values of the same occurrence will be nan.

The final data frame I am looking for will look like,

```
df
col1    col2
  1       A
  2       NA
  3       B
  4       C
  5       NA
  6       NA
  7       B
  8       NA
  9       A
```

I can do it using for loop and comparing, But the execution time will be more. I am looking for pythonic way to do it. Some panda shortcuts may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values and missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].where(df['col2'].ne(df['col2'].shift()))
#alternative
#df['col2'] = np.where(df['col2'].ne(df['col2'].shift()), df['col2'], np.nan)
```

Or by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with inverted condition by `~`:

```
df.loc[~df['col2'].ne(df['col2'].shift()), 'col2'] = np.nan
```

Or thanks @Daniel Mesejo - use `eq` for `==`:

```
df.loc[df['col2'].eq(df['col2'].shift()), 'col2'] = np.nan
```

---

```
print (df)
   col1 col2
0     1    A
1     2  NaN
2     3    B
3     4    C
4     5  NaN
5     6  NaN
6     7    B
7     8  NaN
8     9    A
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['col2'].ne(df['col2'].shift()))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8     True
Name: col2, dtype: bool
```